# I want to create a REST mock service with path parameters in SOAPUI

Tags: soapui

I want to create a REST mock service with path parameters in SOAPUI.

Something like http://localhost:8080/orders/{orderId}/waybills/{waybill}

Is it possible to define a mock PUT method with that type of path parameter? Is it possible to parse the parameters and use them in the output response?

I know I have to write a script in groovy but I don't know how to do it, can I ask for help?

Comment: Did you try the documentation? https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing-mocking/service-mocking-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best place to start is the [soapUI sample projects](https://www.soapui.org/learn/tutorials/web-service-example-projects.html).

Your soapUI installer should also give you an option to install some simple SOAP and REST projects that you can explore and experiment with.